# Distinguishing parts of a proof

Tags: formatting, proof-package

Suppose I have a theorem that says that three statements are equivalent. When writing out a proof of such a theorem, I like to use the following formatting:

> *Proof:* (͟1͟)͟ ͟=͟>͟ ͟(͟2͟)͟ **|** *proof here*
>
> (͟2͟)͟ ͟=͟>͟ ͟(͟1͟)͟ **|**    *proof here*
>
> etc.

Is there a nice way to do something like this in LaTeX? I'm not sure if this has a name, so I wasn't able to figure out if it had already been asked.

Comment: You might use a customised description environment for that, for instance. Do you want  those rules, oor are they here to make your question clearer?

Comment: I just type in `(x)$\implies$(y)` and leave a blank line before the parts from the second on.